# Slideshow with FadeOut/FadeIn events, using Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I built a fairly simple slideshow, but can't quite figure out how to incorporate the fade in / fade out effect. I've read that it's best to use JQuery, but some have suggested that standard JavaScript would also do the trick - in any case, I've tried several scripts, but none seem to work. If someone here could help, I'd be in their debt!

Here's my code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var Image = new Array("pics/21cents.png", "pics/22cents.png", "pics/23cents.png");
    var Image_Number = 0;
    var Image_Length = Image.length - 1;
    var x;
    function change_image(num) {
        Image_Number = Image_Number + num;
        if (Image_Number > Image_Length) {
            Image_Number = 0;
        }
        if (Image_Number < 0) {
            Image_Number = Image_Length;
        }
        document.slideshow1.src=Image[Image_Number];
        return false;
    }
    function auto() {
        x = setInterval("change_image(-1)", 5000);  
    }
    function stop() {
        clearInterval(x);
    }
    auto();
</script>
```

Comment: Probably there isn't an easy way to do this without some libraray, see this question : [fade effect using javascript no jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104053/fade-effect-using-javascript-no-jquery). With jQuery you could really shorten the code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by far by using jQuery. In addition to a handful of useful UI effects (e.g. `slideDown()`, `fadeOut()`, etc), you also get the ability to select and manipulate DOM elements with ease.

For example, if you were going to use jQuery it would be as easy as something like:

```
var $img = $("<img>").css({"display": "none"}).prop("src", "http://placehold.it/500x500");
$("div").html($img);
$("img").fadeIn();
```

Otherwise to get the fadeIn/Out effect you will have to set somesort of `setInterval()` loop, changing the opacity by a percentage at each iteration. E.G.:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var img = document.getElementById("image");

    var opacity = img.style.opacity;
    if(opacity !== 1) {
        img.style.opacity += 0.01;
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks man, I decided to use the JavaScript code you listed.....but how would you add this code to my existing JavaScript code for the slideshow? Would I open a separate script tag and paste it in there or would I paste that code inside the same JS tag up there? Thanks again!

Comment: Do you mean the jQuery code or the opacity thing? (ps if you like the answer you can accept it :) )

Comment: The opacity thing! :)

Comment: The code I gave was just a simple example - have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104053/fade-effect-using-javascript-no-jquery for more detailed answers