# Window load (and fade out) without JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a smaller site, where JQuery is not an option. **What I want is to wait until the whole page (incl. images) has loaded (show a CSS loader while the page is loading) and then fade out the CSS loader.**

I have the code that works in JQuery:

```
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.loader').fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

**How can I achieve that without JQuery, *the CSS loader is already implemented and working, no need to do anything there*** (I've never worked without JQuery for any of my projects unfortunately)?

Comment: you might find interesting answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104053/fade-effect-using-javascript-no-jquery or here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/fade-in-and-fade-out-in-pure-javascript

Comment: ...and i found a jsfiddle implementation too: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/cMp7s/

Comment: answer to your question is located here..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121203/how-to-do-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-javascript-and-css

Comment: @Hawk - I don't want to just fade something in and out with opacity, but wait for page load and then set a css element to `display:block` with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, take a look at this code. => <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/vemokuwe/2/edit)**</kbd>

I've tested it and it's working. This code also works in legacy browsers (such as `IE8` etc).

1. First, we attach an event listener to our element (`window`).
2. Then we define the `function` (`function fadeOut`) which will animate the `opacity` property.
3. You have to pass options/parameters to our `fadeOut` function.

Under the `first (element)` parameter you have to specify the `element` that is to be animated. The `second (startLevel)` parameter is the level the animation should `start` from. The `third (endLevel)` parameter is the level the animation should `stop` at. The `forth (duration)` parameter is the duration of our animation. Finally the `fifth (callback)` option is a callback, which means when our animation completes, you will get notified and also can pass some additional code.

**Javascript**

```
function attach(element,listener,ev,tf){

if(element.attachEvent) {

    element.attachEvent("on"+listener,ev);

}else{

    element.addEventListener(listener,ev,tf);

}

}

function fadeOut(element,startLevel,endLevel,duration,callback){

var fOInt;

    op = startLevel;

fOInt = setInterval(function() {

    if(op<=endLevel){

    element.style.opacity = endLevel;
    element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = " + endLevel + ")";

    clearInterval(fOInt);

        if(typeof callback == 'function') callback(true);

    }else{

    op -= 0.1;

    element.style.opacity = op;
    element.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = " + op*100 + ")";

    }

    },duration);

}

attach(window,'load',function(){

    fadeOut(document.getElementById('loader'),1,0,50,function(cb){

    alert('The loader has faded out!')

    });

},false);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='loader' id='loader'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.loader{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:5px solid red;
    background-color:brown;
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);    
}
```

Comment: @Paranoia, take a look at the demo.

Comment: Great, that worked. I just removed the alert obviously, but otherwise, perfect! :) Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
window.onload=function(){

 var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0];
  ele.style.transition="opacity 1s";
  setTimeout(function(){ele.style.opacity=0;},0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML COde

```
<span id="loader" style="background-color:#069;padding:30px;text-align:center;">Loading...</span>
```

JS Code

```
window.onload = function () {
fade('loader');
}
var TimeToFade = 2000;

function fade(eid) {
var element = document.getElementById(eid);
if (element == null) return;
if (element.FadeState == null) {
    if (element.style.opacity == null || element.style.opacity == '' || element.style.opacity == '1') {
        element.FadeState = 2;
    } else {
        element.FadeState = -2;
    }
}

if (element.FadeState == 1 || element.FadeState == -1) {
    element.FadeState = element.FadeState == 1 ? -1 : 1;
    element.FadeTimeLeft = TimeToFade - element.FadeTimeLeft;
} else {
    element.FadeState = element.FadeState == 2 ? -1 : 1;
    element.FadeTimeLeft = TimeToFade;
    setTimeout("animateFade(" + new Date().getTime() + ",'" + eid + "')", 33);
}
}

function animateFade(lastTick, eid) {
var curTick = new Date().getTime();
var elapsedTicks = curTick - lastTick;

var element = document.getElementById(eid);

if (element.FadeTimeLeft <= elapsedTicks) {
    element.style.opacity = element.FadeState == 1 ? '1' : '0';
    element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = ' + (element.FadeState == 1 ? '100' : '0') + ')';
    element.FadeState = element.FadeState == 1 ? 2 : -2;
    return;
}

element.FadeTimeLeft -= elapsedTicks;
var newOpVal = element.FadeTimeLeft / TimeToFade;
if (element.FadeState == 1) newOpVal = 1 - newOpVal;

element.style.opacity = newOpVal;
element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity = ' + (newOpVal * 100) + ')';

setTimeout("animateFade(" + curTick + ",'" + eid + "')", 33);
}
```