# How to fade all divs in a container except one without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fade HTML element with raw javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695462/fade-html-element-with-raw-javascript)

Any one Know Javascript trick to do this ?
Actually I dont want any other libraries to do this..

Comment: Show at least what is your current html structure and show what you have maybe tried so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but this code should help ya

```
document.getElementById('ELEMENT-ID').style.opacity = 0.4;
document.getElementById('ELEMENT-ID').style.filter = "alpha(opacity=40)";
```

You may use

`getElementsByTagName("div")` or `getElementsByClassName("CLASS-NAME")` to filter ahead.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

What is the one that you don't want to fade?

if it's the one that got a click, let's imagine:

```
<div id="container">
   <ul>
       <li>Item 1</li>
       <li>Item 2</li>
       <li>Item 3</li>
       <li>Item 4</li>
       <li>Item 5</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and you have hooked up the `click` event to all `li` elements

```
$("#container li").click(function() { });
```

you can simple do:

```
$("#container li").click(function() { 
    $("#container li").not(this).fadeIn();
});
```

live example [with opacity](http://jsbin.com/asixam/edit#javascript,html,live)

without any framework to help you out, you will end up writing a lot of code...

for example you can see that only to hook up the `onDomReady` is a lot awful code in this answer

> [javascript domready?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206937/javascript-domready)

And **worst that all this**, is that you need to write code to each browser version, as there are so many engines and the same code will never work on all of them, the big question is:

Do you really want to go **without jQuery**?

Comment: As long as you provide reasons for why jQuery should be used, it's fine. But you didn't when I wrote my comment. Although I think that DOM ready is not an argument. You can always put your code at the end of the `body` which will be sufficient for most situations. And as you may have seen in the question in linked to as duplicate, writing your own simple fade script is actually not that difficult (though it might not be x-browser compatible). Of course jQuery provides many more features in this regard.