# How to create fadein effect in JavaScript using for-loop and anonymous function call

Tags: javascript, for-loop, fadein, fade

i am creating a simple fadein effect using pure javascript. For this i have tried three methods. **M1** is using recursive functionality and **M2** is based on for loop and anonymous function and **M3** is based on for loop and string based function call.

Under **M1** the code is giving perfect output as a fadein effect.

But under **M2** the fadein effect does not work and the content directly goes visible after a specified duration.

Now again under **M3** the fadein effect is generated.

Can anyone guide me that how to generate fadein effect based on **M2**. Means using **for loop** and anonymous function call.

**M1**------ Works perfectly------  http://jsfiddle.net/TH2dn/7/

```
function starter(){
    var i = 0;
    var el = document.getElementById("div1");
    fadeIn(el,i);
}

function fadeIn(el,i) {

    i = i + 0.01;
    seto(el,i);
    if (i<1){setTimeout(function(){fadeIn(el,i);}, 10);}
}

function seto(el,i)
{
    el.style.opacity = i;
}

starter();
```

**M2**------Does not work------  http://jsfiddle.net/TH2dn/13/

```
function starter(){
    var i = 0;
    var el = document.getElementById("div1");
    fadeIn(el,i);
}

function fadeIn(el,i) {

    for ( i = 0 ; i<=1 ; i = i + 0.01){
    setTimeout( function(){ seto(el,i); } , i * 1000);}
}

function seto(el,i)
{
    el.style.opacity = i;
}

starter();
```

While using JSHint in the JSFiddle on **M2** it says that --" Don't make functions within a loop "

**M3**------Works Properly------ jsfiddle.net/TH2dn/9/

```
var i = 0;
var el = document.getElementById("div1");

function fadeIn() {
    for ( i = 0 ; i<=1 ; i = i + 0.01){
        setTimeout("seto(" + i + ")", i * 1000);
    }
}

function seto(i)
{
    el.style.opacity = i;
}
```

---

The abopve question is based on [Pure JavaScript fade in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244338/pure-javascript-fade-in-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it says that --" Don't make functions within a loop "

That's good advice, but it isn't your (main) problem here.

Your problem is that you are invoking every functions 1 second from right now.  They will execute in a random order, starting in 1 second and firing as fast as they can.

Do this:

```
function fadeIn(el) {
    var go = function(j) {
       setTimeout( function(){ seto(el,j); } , j *1000);}
    };

    for (var i = 0 ; i<=1 ; i = i + 0.01) go(i);
}
```

Comment: its the perfect answer to my question... Just one thing more... in my **M2** i am directly placing the setTimeout and its anonymous function call under the for-loop and in your answer you are following the same by creating a function outside the loop and calling it from inside the loop. And it works...??? am trying to know that whats the difference...?

Comment: Ah, a *huge* difference.  In your version, `i` is local to the function fadeIn, so every call to `seto` it will have the same value (because it's the same variable).  In my version, `j` is local to `go`, so it has the value that `i` had *at the time that `go` was called*.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the complete answer to the question...

**ANS2** --- [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TH2dn/12/)

```
function fin(){
    var i = 0;
    var el = document.getElementById("div1");
    fadeIn(el,i);
}

function fadeIn(el,i) {
    var go = function(i) {
        setTimeout( function(){ seto(el,i); } , i * 1000);
    };
    for ( i = 0 ; i<=1 ; i = i + 0.01) go(i);
}

function seto(el,i)
{
    el.style.opacity = i;
}
```

Thanks to Malvolio