# Image change onclick using javascript is very fast?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Html and Javascript code:

```
<img  src="imgs/right.gif" id="image_change" onclick="changeImage()"/>

<script>
    function changeImage() {
var src = document.getElementById("image_change").src;  
    var imgsrc = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    if  (imgsrc == "left.gif")
    {
        document.getElementById("image_change").src = "imgs/right.gif";
        alert('if'+document.getElementById("image_change").src);
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("image_change").src = "imgs/left.gif";
        alert('else'+document.getElementById("image_change").src);
    }

}
</script>
```

When i click on the image, a new image is replacing in fraction of milli seconds..can i  make the replacing of the image slow by using javascript or by adding any css class to it??any help would be appreciated..

Comment: *Replacing* an image source will always immediately remove the current image and start loading (or showing if cached) the next one. If you have *two* image tags, load next image in the hidden one, then increase its opacity while decreasing the opacity of the shown one (whether in JS, or with CSS transitions, both are possible).

Comment: please give me some referenc code so that i can test it in my code.. @Amadan

Comment: Search for "crossfade images css" or "crossfade images javascript", many tutorials around for those keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [***setTimeout()***](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function of window object to make delay for execution of your code.

Try this :

**HTML :**

```
<img src="http://www.hdwallpapers-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Cartoon-6.jpg" id="image_change" onclick="changeImage();" />
```

**javaScript :**

```
function changeImage() {
    var src = document.getElementById("image_change").src;  
    var imgsrc = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    if  (imgsrc == "Cartoon-6.jpg")
    {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("image_change").src = "http://topwallpaperswide.com/wp-content/uploads/cartoon-wallpapers-jerry-the-mouse-running-and-shouting-20140823213658-53f9097a18af8.jpg";
        //alert('if'+document.getElementById("image_change").src);
        }, 1000);
    }
    else 
    {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("image_change").src = "http://www.hdwallpapers-3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Cartoon-6.jpg";
        //alert('else'+document.getElementById("image_change").src);
        }, 1000);
    }

}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/hw92wL66/)

Comment: i liked your approach but i think your fiddle is not changing image..please make necessary changes in it.

Comment: Can you try it again? In my case it's changing image and giving alert accordingly with specified delay that is 1000ms or 1sec.

Answer (score 2):

try this

**Using javascript**

```
   var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
    element.style.display = 'block';
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op >= 1){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op += op * 0.1;
        alert("here");
    }, 10);
    var img =document.getElementById("image_change");
    fade(img);// Chnage image in fade method
```

**Using jquery**

```
// increase the 500 to larger values to increase the duration 
// of the fadeout and/or fadein
$('#image_change').fadeOut(500, function () {
    $('#image_change').attr("src", "/newImage.png");
    $('#image_change').fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: But you tagged jquery with it . Let me try using javascript

Comment: I removed that Tag, and OP asked question that using Javascript

Comment: I have added `javscript` part also

Answer (score 1):

The above jQuery way is straight forward and easy , if you want this in vanilla JavaScript you can use setTimeout with opacity to create fade out and fade in effect for further details check link below

[Pure JavaScript fade in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244338/pure-javascript-fade-in-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```js
function changeImage() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var src = document.getElementById("image_change").src;
    if (src == "http://s25.postimg.org/iyly1k3uz/arrow_left.png") {
      document.getElementById("image_change").src = "http://s25.postimg.org/tzh36kw3v/arrow_right.png";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("image_change").src = "http://s25.postimg.org/iyly1k3uz/arrow_left.png";
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://s25.postimg.org/tzh36kw3v/arrow_right.png" id="image_change" onclick="changeImage()" />
```