# Javascript callback function not working in fadeOut/ fadeIn CSS3 Transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 'div' that I 'fadeOut' after pressing a button using javascript.  After the 'div' has faded out I would like it to 'fadeIn'.  This is presently not happening for me.  I understand the concept of the callback function but I appear not to have succeeded in implementing it in my code. Please can someone advise? I would like a callback function solution if that is possible.

```js
function fade_effect(element, callback) {

  var x = function(element) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(element);
    elem.style.transition = "opacity 2.0s linear 0s";
    elem.style.opacity = 0;
    return elem;
  }

  var thisElement = x(element);
  fadeIn(thisElement);
}

function fadeIn(element_input) {
  element_input.style.transition = "opacity 2.0s linear 0s";
  element_input.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

```css
div#box1 {
  background: #9dceff;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fade_effect('box1',fadeIn);">Magenta</button>
<div id="box1">Content in box 1 ...</div>
```

Comment: might it be because your `fadeIn` function is accepting a `element_input` attribute and you're trying to use `elem` inside the function?

Comment: `x()` takes one argument, why are you calling it with two arguments?

Comment: `fade_in` is using a variable `elem` that hasn't been defined. There's a variable with this name in `x`, but its scope is local to that function.

Comment: @Barmar, I have fixed the one argument x() issue.  as the code stands above, nothing actually works, no fading out nor in.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're trying to overcomplicate things. Knowing that the transition lasts 2 seconds, you can use a simple JavaScript timeout to fade it back in when it has completed.

```
function fade_effect(element){
    var elem=document.getElementById(element);
    elem.style.transition="opacity 2s linear";
    elem.style.opacity=0;
    setTimeout(function(){
        elem.style.opacity=1;
    },2000);
}
```

Comment: That assumes that JavaScript and CSS both use accurate timers (they don't) and requires that you maintain the two seconds in two different places.

Comment: True on both points. However, in all the time I've been using `setTiemout` to delay an action until a transition has completed, I've never seen the discrepancies be noticeable to the naked eye. For maintenance purposes, if necessary, a variable could be used to hold the time instead.

Comment: it it possible to get a callback solution similar to the one I am trying to get above?

Comment: @dave See the duplicate question, it answers your question preciselyl.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names are just mis-matched on the fadeIn function.

```
function fadeIn(element_input) {
  element_input.style.transition = "opacity 2.0s linear 0s";
  element_input.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

Comment: fixed it. still not working

Comment: I mis-read. it looked at first glance like fixing the javascript exception was what you were after. It looks like you want to write a pure javascript animation for fadein/out. 

If you are using jquery already though, it would be easier with that. 
Check that out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244338/pure-javascript-fade-in-function