# Javascript Add fadeIn to the loading Div

Tags: javascript

I have this code which loads an external local page into a div:

```
function load(url) {

    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="'+url+'"></object>';
    return false;


}
```

How can I make it fadeIn instead of just appearing? I would prefer if it was pure javascript

Comment: can you use jQuery?

Comment: I would try jQuery or css animations.

Comment: That was my first option but I'm trying to avoid needing to use third party libraries for this. So I'm looking for something in pure javascript

Comment: Did you try to google "css fade in"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice fadeIn function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244338/pure-javascript-fade-in-function) and applied it to your load function.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hwj4278j/1/)

```
function load(url) {
  var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  myDiv.innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="'+url+'"></object>';
  fadeIn(myDiv);
  return false;
}

function fadeIn(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 0;
  var tick = function() {
    el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity + 0.01;
    if (+el.style.opacity < 1) {
      (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) || setTimeout(tick, 16)
    }
  };
  tick();
}

load('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so is to add to your html jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

And then in your js file use .fadeIn() method on myDiv.
Remember to link jQuery before you link the .js file

Comment: That was my first option but I'm trying to avoid needed to use third party libraries for this. So I'm looking for something in pure javascript

Answer (score 0):

Or if you can't use jQuery create animate classes in css:

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
to {
   opacity: 1;
   }
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
 animation: fadeIn .5s ease-in 1 forwards;
}

.is-paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

and then use this code in js:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.js-fade');
if (el.classList.contains('is-paused')){
el.classList.remove('is-paused');
}
```

The last thing you need to do is to add to myDiv classes of js-fade and fade-in is-paused.
The aforementioned code is qute general so adapt it to your needs