# 'FadeIn' and 'FadeOut' don't work

Tags: javascript

I've created two functions called 'FadeIn' and 'FadeOut' because i can't use jQuery but they don't work, i don't know why. They directly set the opacity to 0 or 1 without doing it gradually. This is the code:

```
function fadeIn(el){
    var val = 0;
    document.getElementById(el).style.opacity = val;
    function fade(){
        val += .1;
        document.getElementById(el).style.opacity = val;
        if (val < 1){
            setTimeout(fade(), 90);
        }
    }
    fade();   
}

function fadeOut(el){
    var val = 1;
    document.getElementById(el).style.opacity = val;
    function fade(){
        val -= .1;
        document.getElementById(el).style.opacity = val;
        if (val > 0){
            setTimeout(fade(), 90);
        }
    }
    fade();   
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure JavaScript fade in function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23244338/pure-javascript-fade-in-function)

Comment: It's likely `style.opacity` gets reported as a string, so you'll first need to parse it to a float to do maths on it. Furthermore, why not just add/remove a class that invokes a pure CSS fade?

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. when you give `fade()` instead of `fade` as the first argument, the function invokes itself, and your `setTimeout()` does nothing. this should work:

```
function fadeIn(el){
    var val = 0;
    document.getElementById(el).style.opacity = val;
    function fade(){
        val += .1;
        document.getElementById(el).style.opacity = val;
        if (val < 1){
            setTimeout(fade, 90); // A Small fix to your code
        }
    }
    fade();
}
```

`fadeOut()` will be fixed the same way.